# How to check the NSString contains the '%' or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I want to ask a question about the objective C. Does the NSString * contains some functions to check the NSString * contains some string in the UITextField.text? For example

```
NSString *checkString = @"abcd%"

if(checkString contains '%') // I want this function
   return YES;
else
   return NO;
```

Comment: UITextField always contains a string.

Comment: @jtbandes, thank you for your reply. I have change the question based on the comments. Please take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString`. The code will look something like:

> ```
> NSRange range = [UITextField.text rangeOfString:@"!"];
>
> if (range.length > 0){
>   NSLog(@"String contains '!'");
> }
> else {
>   NSLog(@"No '!' found in string");
> }
> ```

Comment: range.length is NSUinteger. it's always >= 0
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW23)

Comment: Thanks, that's right. I've edited my comment. It should be >0.

Answer (score 43):

```
if([checkString rangeOfString:@"%"].location != NSNotFound)
    // hooray!
```

Comment: On one line, like we love them!

Comment: `if([checkString rangeOfString:@"%"].length) //even more concise`

Answer (score 2):

The code from the previous post is not correct

```
NSRange range = [UITextField.text rangeOfString:@"!"];

if (range.length >= 0){
  NSLog(@"String contains '!'");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"No '!' found in string");
}
```

It should be "range.length > 0"